# Ruby How to serialize a string or increment a string when duplicating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, increment

**EXPLANATION**

I am trying to take a phrase/name of an object and to serialize or to increment the name when the object is being duplicated. So, for instance here is the model:

```
create_table "forwarders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint   "site_id", null: false
    t.string   "phrase"
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "redirect_count", default: 0, null: false

    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

    t.index ["site_id"], name: "index_forwarders_on_site_id"
end
```

Now, here is the object of that model that I want to duplicate:

```
{ 
  id: 19,
  site_id: 1, 
  phrase: "test",
  url: "https://google.com",
  redirect_count: 9,
  created_at: Tue, 10 May 2022 01:48:29.791141000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 10 May 2022 01:55:04.214172000 UTC +00:00
}
```

When duplicating this, I want to increment the `phrase` similar to what happens on a computer when copying and pasting to the same folder. So, the new `phrase` should be 'test_1', or if already 'test_1' it should become 'test_2'.

**MY SOLUTION**

I will post the answer I have come up with after doing much searching online. This is the most elegant solution that I could come up with; but, my question is...

**QUESTION**

...does Ruby already has a string Class that will do this? I have not been able to find one.

Comment: Do we have to know anything about ActiveRecord or Rails to answer this question?  Or are you just looking for a pure Ruby function that takes a string and increments the number at the end, but if it doesn't have a number at the end then it adds "_0" to the string?  What if you have one specific object that gets duplicated twice... is it OK that both of the duplicates will have the same name?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer that I have come up with.

**METHOD**

```
def serialize_phrase(phrase)
  phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ? phrase + '_1' : phrase.next
end
```

**EXPLANATION**

The method is called like so `serialize_phrase("test")`

The first part `phrase.split("_")` looks for an underscore and creates an array of all parts. In this case it is an array with only one value `["test"]`. (The reason it looks for an underscore is because that is how I am serializing the phrases, by adding an underscore and a number.) Here's some examples:

```
phrase = "test"
phrase.split("_")    #  ["test"]
phrase = "test_1"
phrase.split("_")    #  ["test", "1"]
phrase = "test_1_3"
phrase.split("_")    #  ["test", "1", "3"]
phrase = "test1_14"
phrase.split("_")    #  ["test1", "14"]
```

The second part `.last` returns the last location in the array. Using the examples above, you'd get this:

```
phrase = "test"
phrase.split("_").last    #  "test"
phrase = "test_1"
phrase.split("_").last    #  "1"
phrase = "test_1_3"
phrase.split("_").last    #  "3"
phrase = "test1_14"
phrase.split("_").last    #  "14"
```

The third part `.to_i` changes the result to an integer. Using the examples above, you'd get this:

```
phrase = "test"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i    #  0
phrase = "test_1"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i    #  1
phrase = "test_1_3"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i    #  3
phrase = "test1_14"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i    #  14
```

Notice how if the value of the last part in the array is not able to be converted to an integer, then the conversion returns a `0` value. This will help us in the next part to determine if the phrase needs to be incremented by 1 or appended with '_1'. By checking for a value of 0, we get the following results from the examples above:

```
phrase = "test"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ?   #  true
phrase = "test_1"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ?   #  false
phrase = "test_1_3"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ?   #  false
phrase = "test1_14"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ?   #  false
```

The next part `phrase + '_1' : phrase.next` is designed as a one line if statement. If the result of `== 0 ?` is `true` then `phrase + '_1'` is returned, else `phrase.next` is returned. `phrase + '_1'` just adds '_1' to the end of the phrase that was evaluated. `.next` is a Ruby Class that increments a string.

(Side Note:) `.next` is a handy Class that can determine the full integer at the end of a string and increase by 1 (So, 'test_14' will be 'test_15'). The problem with this Class for my needs is that if the phrase "test" has `.next` called on it the result is "tesu". A nice thing for it to be able to do (get the next alphabetic value), but not what I am wanting.

Here are the results of the examples that have been used so far.

```
phrase = "test"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ? phrase + '_1' : phrase.next  #  "tesu"
phrase = "test_1"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ? phrase + '_1' : phrase.next  #  "test_2"
phrase = "test_1_3"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ? phrase + '_1' : phrase.next  #  "test_1_4"
phrase = "test1_14"
phrase.split("_").last.to_i == 0 ? phrase + '_1' : phrase.next  #  "test_15"
```

**KNOWN PROBLEM**

If the phrase is "test_0", then the result given will be "test_0_1", not "test_1".